# Taking DateTime input in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, datetime, razor, blazor

I'm trying to take "Meeting data" as input from users.

I have a modal like this:

```
div class="simple-form">
    <EditForm Model="meeting" OnValidSubmit="SubmitForm">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Location</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="meeting.Location" class="form-control" placeholder="Adres Giriniz" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => meeting.Location)" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date</label>
            <InputDate @bind-Value="meeting.Date" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => meeting.Date)" />
        </div>



        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button @onclick="Cancel" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code {

    Meetings meeting = new Meetings();
    ...
```

and this model return `meeting` object to main page where I Post it to database:

```
Meetings meeting;

    async Task ShowModal()
    {
        var MeetingModal = Modal.Show<MeetingRequestComponent>();
        var result = await MeetingModal.Result;

        if (!result.Cancelled)
        {
            meeting = (Meetings)result.Data;
            meeting.ReceiverId = id;
            meeting.SenderId = _userId;
            await http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Meetings", meeting);
        }
    }
```

---

Model for Date info is just `DateTime` :

```
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

But I couldn't get the time information.

- I tried to use `<input type="datetime" bind="meeting.Date">` but it did not work. I couldn't take both Date and Time value. It discarded given time value and set as 12:00:00 AM
- I tried to create another column in the database for Hour and Minutes Data only but it asks for `bytes[]`.

Expected Behavior :

[image: DatePicker]

Date Picker like this and time picker ("HH:mm")

How can I take time information as input?

How do I set an initial value to a date? (This was problematic because I get some error saying that I cannot use Value with @bind-Value)

Comment: You can set an initial value by setting `meeting.Date` when you create the value, e.g. `Meetings meeting = new Meetings() { Date = DateTime.Today };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<InputDate>` component only handles creating a `<input type='date' ...` tag (see original [Blazor code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputDate.cs))

If you want to enter/edit a date-time combination you need to roll your own.

The code in this comment should work:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18078#issuecomment-626997904

As I mentioned in comments, to set an initial value you need to code this when creating the bound object, e.g.

```cs
   Meetings meeting = new Meetings() { Date = DateTime.Now };
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting .NET 6, you can use built in blazor form input component `<InputDate Type="InputDateType.DateTimeLocal"...`. You can also pass the `InputDateType` `enum` as `Type` parameter to component to fit your needs. This will carry both `date` and `time` information entered by user.

```
<InputDate Type="InputDateType.DateTimeLocal"
           min="@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" @bind-Value="@dateTime" />

@code {
    DateTime dateTime;
}
```

Available Options,

| Field | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date | 0 | Lets the user enter a date. |
| DateTimeLocal | 1 | Lets the user enter both a date and a time. |
| Month | 2 | Lets the user enter a month and a year. |
| Time | 3 | Lets the user enter a time. |

Refer to the [InputDate component docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputdate-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and the [InputDateType Enum docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputdatetype?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for more details.